# Javascript || operator

Tags: javascript

I am using a large JS library to perform certain drawing operations in canvas. Reviewing the library code (to make accommodating changes), I have ran into the '||' operator being used in a fashion which certainly should not evaluate to Boolean. Does this mean that this is a different operator or am I missing something obvious? An example follows:

```
var $time = Date.now || function(){
return +new Date;
};
```

Comment: I'm guessing it would be if Date.now for some reason returned a 0, then you would instead set $time to the return value of the function...?

Comment: @peirix: You guessed wrong. $time will be a function returning the current Date. It is set to be an alias of Date.now if it is defined (non-false) or the supplied function otherwise.

Comment: Ah, that's why I didn't set it as an answer. No way of downvoting a comment :p So one would have to know more about the `Date.now` variable to know fully how this would work, then?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`||` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) evaluates to the first operand if it can be converted to true or the last operand otherwise. So in your example `$time` will be `Date.now` if it exists or the declared function otherwise.

Comment: The first non-False operant, that is.

Comment: Not the first operand that can be converted to true. The last expression is used even if it would be converted to false.

Answer (score 17):

There is already an accepted answer, but I like to mention, that the OR-Operator is also called Default-Operator, because it doesn't return a boolean, but instead the left or right hand argument.

Same goes for the AND-Operator, which is also called guard-Operator.

Check out [crockford's Survey of the JavaScript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html) for more details:

> The && operator is commonly called logical and. It can also be called guard. If the first operand is false, null, undefined, "" (the empty string), or the number 0 then it returns the first operand. Otherwise, it returns the second operand. This provides a convenient way to write a null-check:
>
> var value = p && p.name; /* The name value will
>   only be retrieved from p if p has a value, avoiding an error. */
>
> The || operator is commonly called logical or. It can also be called default. If the first operand is false, null, undefined, "" (the empty string), or the number 0, then it returns the second operand. Otherwise, it returns the first operand. This provides a convenient way to specify default values:
>
> value = v || 10; /* Use the value of v, but if v
>   doesn't have a value, use 10 instead. */

Answer (score 0):

This is very common is javascript. If Data.now evaluates to true, then $time is set to that, else it is set to the function.

Comment: The function doesn't have () attached to the closing brace, so $time is set to the function, not it's output.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that code is saying if the `DateTime.now` variable does not exist, instead return the result of `+new Date`.

Comment: It could also be saying DateTime.now is '', 0, false, null

Answer (score 0):

The `||` operator is being used to assign a value to `$time` in the example.

If `Date.now` evaluates to false, then `$time` is assigned the value on the right side of the `||` operator (in this case, a function). If `Date.now` evaluates to true, then it short-cicuits and assigns the value of Date.now to `$time`