# How to add If statement when appending strings Javascript

Tags: javascript

Good day,

I was confused on how am I be able to add an If statement inside my loop when appending strings.

heres my code

```
html += '<tr><td></td>'+
            '<td>'+moment(x.date_at).format('MM/DD/YYYY') +'</td>'+
            '<td>'+x.transactionType+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+x.id+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+if(x.description!=null){x.description}+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+x.ref_no+'</td>'+
            '<td class="align-right">'+x.debit+'</td>'+
            '<td class="align-right">'+x.credit+'</td>'+
            '<td class="align-right">'+val+'</td></tr>';
    });
```

I am then getting a syntax error error on the IF part. Thanks for the help. its been a while since I code thats why im a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just place an `if` statement anywhere in your code. If you need to get this functionality in that place you need to use a ternary if operator `?:`

```
html += '<tr><td></td>'+
            '<td>'+moment(x.date_at).format('MM/DD/YYYY') +'</td>'+
            '<td>'+x.transactionType+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+x.id+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+ (x.description!=null ? x.description : '')+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+x.ref_no+'</td>'+
            '<td class="align-right">'+x.debit+'</td>'+
            '<td class="align-right">'+x.credit+'</td>'+
            '<td class="align-right">'+val+'</td></tr>';
```

If you want to use `if` anyway, you should introduce a variable that will hold the resulting value:

```
var temp = '';
if (x.description != null)
temp = x.description;
html += '<tr><td></td>'+
            '<td>'+moment(x.date_at).format('MM/DD/YYYY') +'</td>'+
            '<td>'+x.transactionType+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+x.id+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+ temp +'</td>'+
            '<td>'+x.ref_no+'</td>'+
            '<td class="align-right">'+x.debit+'</td>'+
            '<td class="align-right">'+x.credit+'</td>'+
            '<td class="align-right">'+val+'</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that quick answer @Vsevolod! Im really confused why I am getting that error coz I thought Its really correct syntax.. anyways thank you very much for clearing this one out for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [shorthand if/else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11069295/1781026) like this:

`html += '<td>'+(x.description!=null ? x.description : '' )+'</td>';`

Inside your code:

```
html += '<tr><td></td>'+
            '<td>'+moment(x.date_at).format('MM/DD/YYYY') +'</td>'+
            '<td>'+x.transactionType+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+x.id+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+(x.description!=null ? x.description : '' )+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+x.ref_no+'</td>'+
            '<td class="align-right">'+x.debit+'</td>'+
            '<td class="align-right">'+x.credit+'</td>'+
            '<td class="align-right">'+val+'</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you only need to break your concatenation like this:

```
html += '<tr><td></td>'+
            '<td>'+moment(x.date_at).format('MM/DD/YYYY') +'</td>'+
            '<td>'+x.transactionType+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+x.id+'</td>';

if(x.description!=null) html+=  '<td>' + {x.description} + '</td>';

html +=     '<td>'+x.ref_no+'</td>'+
            '<td class="align-right">'+x.debit+'</td>'+
            '<td class="align-right">'+x.credit+'</td>'+
            '<td class="align-right">'+val+'</td></tr>';
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **if** like that. The fundamental problem is that in JavaScript **if** is a statement, not an expression, and it doesn't return any value (unlike more strict functional languages like Scala, where everything is an expression and produces a value).

So you have the following options:

1. Use ternary conditional operator ?: which produces a value and actually can be used in an expression:

   ... + x.description? x.description : '' + ...

The only inconvenience is that you always need an else value, so in case of just checking *description* for null, you need to provide an empty string as an alternative. It could be a hassle when you need a lot of fields to print.

2. Use a helper function within the formatting scope. This is an elegant solution in case you have just a single big object to format:

```js
const source = {
  first: 'first',
  second: null,
  third: 'third',
}

function fmt(key) {
  return source[key]? source[key] : ''
}

let html = '<div><hr>'
  + fmt('first') + '<hr>'
  + fmt('second') + '<hr>'
  + fmt('third') + '<hr>'
  + '</div>'
 
document.write(html)
```

3. As a more compact alternative to ?: operator, you can use || operator like this:

```js
   const s = {
      first: 'first',
      second: null,
      third: 'third',
    }

    let html = '<div><hr>'
      + (s.first || '') + '<hr>'
      + (s.second || '') + '<hr>'
      + (s.third || '') + '<hr>'
      + '</div>'
     
    document.write(html)
```

I guess this one is more elegant than #1, since you don't have to repeat property access 2 times :)