# Anything wrong with hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

The value of `!$catalog.hasClass('catalog-fixed')` in line 6 is always true

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
      var $catalog = $(".catalog-brief");
      var sideTop = $catalog.offset().top;
      if (sideTop < 1000){
           // always true
           if (!$catalog.hasClass('catalog-fixed')) $catalog.addClass("catalog-fixed");
      } else {
           if ($catalog.hasClass('catalog-fixed')) $catalog.removeClass("catalog-fixed");
     }
})
```

But this works fine

```js
var $catalog = $(".catalog-brief");
var sideTop = $catalog.offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(){
      if (sideTop < 1000){
           if (!$catalog.hasClass('catalog-fixed')) $catalog.addClass("catalog-fixed");
      } else {
           if ($catalog.hasClass('catalog-fixed')) $catalog.removeClass("catalog-fixed");
     }
})
```

Did I make any mistakes?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `hasClass`, but it seems like you really should be using **`toggleClass`**

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `window.scrollY` instead of the current `sideTop`. Or `$(window).scrollTop()` if you want to use Jquery.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
      var $catalog = $(".catalog-brief");

      // if ($(window).scrollTop() < 1000) {
      if (window.scrollY < 1000) {
           if (!$catalog.hasClass('catalog-fixed')) $catalog.addClass("catalog-fixed");

      } else {
           if ($catalog.hasClass('catalog-fixed')) $catalog.removeClass("catalog-fixed");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
  var $catalog = $(".catalog-brief");
  var sideTop = $catalog.offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function(){
      (sideTop < 1000) &&  ($catalog.toggleClass("catalog-fixed"))
  })
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11069385/1845408