# Run function once only after load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery `load()` to load multiple items. All works good.

```
for(i = 0; i<item.length; i++){
   $( '#parent'+i).load('file'+i+'.html',function(){
       customFunctions();
   });
}
```

My question is, I need to run `customFunctions()` when all completes loading. My above code runs it multiple times. How can I run `customFunctions()` once only after all files complete loading?

Comment: Why dont you just call it at the end of `$(document).ready()`? @Becky

Comment: Your posted code doesn't really make sense. Aren't you passing any data to server? Otherwise, why calling the exact same request in a for loop?

Comment: @Varun thanks but this is triggered after the page loads. So `$(function() { }`will not work.

Comment: Of course it is called multiple times – you are calling it inside a loop!?

Comment: @Varun You don't really need any of those ready events – just include all of your JS at the end of the HTML file.

Comment: @feeela thanks - I know. That's my question I've inlucded it inside the for loop because I'm not certain if it should be out of the `load()`'s callback.

Comment: You should use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead. That will return a promise-like object which you can use [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) on to check that all of the requests are finished

Comment: Wait, you'd have better to explain what is your expected behaviour instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is about making promises, but you could also do this:

```
var all_loaded = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
   $( '#parent' + i).load('file' + i + '.html',function(){
      ++all_loaded == item.length && customFunctions();
   });
}

//++all_loaded: mean It is sum +1 when a file is loaded
```

So when `all_loaded` is equal to `item.length`, the function is loaded just at the end.

Comment: But still doesn't explain the purpose of the `for` loop

Comment: I guess the reason the loop is that he wants to change the filename like `'file' + i + '.html'`

Comment: Ya, that was my first thought before reading OP's comment: `That's my question I've inlucded it inside the for loop because I'm not certain if it should be out of the load()'s callback`. So instead, sounds like a XY problem.

Comment: @Becky This would call exact same request many times, so it cannot be good

Comment: @A.Wolff I prefer `Bhojendra Nepal`'s answer... Any comments on that?

Comment: @Becky That's the exact same behaviour. You should explain instead what is your expected behaviour because your posted code doesn't really make sense. Why would you want to call same request multiple times? (knowing the fact that a HTML file is static)

Comment: @Becky That's SO... Now why don't you explain in question itself expected behaviour??? As i can guessing, you want the `for` loop inside `load()` complete callback, not the opposite

Comment: @Becky That's ok then, makes more sense now. And btw, this asnwer should work as i see it

Comment: @A.Wolff what does the `&&` do?

Comment: @Becky I'm not the poster but that's a shortcut for `if(++all_loaded == item.length) customFunctions();`

Comment: @Becky is equivalent to `if(++all_loaded == item.length){ customFunctions() }`

Comment: @A.Wolff I know I'm very new to coding but never seen that before. Thank you!

Comment: @Becky It is a way of doing things in short. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11069385/1074519)

Comment: why is the ++ is infront of `all_loaded`?

Comment: `++all_loaded` mean It is sum +1 to a variable. Is equivalent to: `all_loaded += 1`

Answer (score 1):

Add counter and update it when each file is loaded. When current value of counter will be equal to total files count you want to load, then call your function;

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i<item.length; i++){
   $( '#parent').load('file.html',function(){
      if(i==(item.length-1))
          customFunctions();
   });
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

*Your function will run only if all load request is successful*

```
var item = {length:12};
runfunction = 0;
for(i = 0; i<item.length; i++){
   $( '#parent').load('t.html',function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){

      if (textStatus == "success") {
            runfunction++;
       }
       /* you can write three line of code any where even after for loop according to your requirements*/
       if(runfunction == item.length ){
        customFunctions();
       }
   });
}

function customFunctions(){
 alert(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options.

You can just keep track in your loop:

```
var loadedCount = 0;
for(i = 0; i<item.length; i++){
  $( '#parent').load('file.html',function(){
    loadedCount++;
    if (loadedCount === item.length) {
      customFunctions();
    }
  });
}
```

That will get the job done for this specific case. This *only works* in this constrained design where you know how many times you are calling and can trust/believe that none of your AJAX requests will fail. As a result, it is not a very stable design.