# how to concat string with dynamic value if that value exists

Tags: javascript, string

Suppose I have a variable `data`:

```
var data = 6;
```

If we have `data` value and it's greater than 5 then the output should be:

```
"Hello x, 6 is your promo code"
```

If we don't have a `data` value, or the value is less than 5 then the output should be:

```
"Hello x"
```

How can I do this with a single line of JavaScript?

Comment: if (data >= 6) return "Hello x, 6 is your promo code"; else return "Hello x"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript if else shorthand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069278/javascript-if-else-shorthand)

Comment: I am feel ironic, it's impossible you can't solve this simple problem since your reputation is high enough..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var numb = 12;
var msg = "Hello x" + (numb > 5 ? (', ' + numb + ' is your promo code') : '');
console.log(msg);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
document.write(data > 5? "Hello x, 6 is your promo code" : "Hello x");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

> The **conditional (ternary) operator** is the only JavaScript operator that takes three operands. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement.

```js
var data = 6,
    promo = data > 5 ? "Hello x, 6 is your promo code" : 'Hello x';

console.log(promo);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
(data>5) ? "Hello x," +6+" is your promo code" : "Hello x
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var x=3;
    alert('Hello' + ((typeof(x) =='undefined' || x<5) ? ' x, ' : ', ' +x + ' is your promo code'));
```

Comment: var x=32;
alert('Hello' + ((typeof(x) =='undefined' || x<5) ? ' x, ' : ', your promo code is '+x));

It also ensures that variable x is declared ... If it is not declared, the result would be 'Hello x, '

Answer (score 1):

I will say, it's a simple ternary operator

```js
var data = 6,
    minVal = 5;

var promo = data > minVal ? "Hello x, " + data + " is your promo code" : 'Hello x';

console.log(promo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the [Template literals syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

For example: `${data > 5 ? "Hello x, 6 is your promo code" : "Hello x"}``

Answer (score 0):

There's a magic way with JS that kinda breaks your brain but it works

```js
var numValue = 6
var finalValue = `Hello X${numValue > 5 && `, ${numValue} is your promo code` || ''}`

console.log(finalValue)
// Hello X, 6 is your promo code
```

Where if the numValue=5

```js
const numValue = 5
const finalValue = `Hello X${numValue > 5 && `, ${numValue} is your promo code` || ''}`

console.log(finalValue)
// Hello X
```

So in case `numValue > 5` is `true` the returned value be `${numValue} is your promo code` but if it's false then we need to add the `|| ''` to return an empty string or you will have `false` in your string.

It's not a clean solution but it's a solution to consider

But for your own benefit and others when reading the code the conventional ways are better

Example:

```js
const n = 6
let fv = "Hello X"

fv += n > 5 ? `, ${n} is your promo code` : ''

console.log(fv)
// Hello X, 6 is your promo code
```

Or the other ways suggested above altho some of those examples look like an overkill

GLHF :)