# Why doesn't my conditional operator work?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

Why does this function return `undefined` instead of "old"?

```
function test(age) {
  12 < age ? "old" : "young";
}

test(15);
```

Comment: because this is not valid javascript. read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069278/javascript-if-else-shorthand

Comment: actually it is valid javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is fine. You need to `return`

```js
function test(age) {
  return 12 < age ? "old" : "young";
}

console.log(test(15));
```

When you leave off a `return` statement, a function returns `undefined` by default.