# What are the troubles (list) that short-circuiting in coding can generate?

Tags: javascript

I read there are some positions against short-circuiting for code readability. I do not ask opinions here. I'm asking a list of troubles (if any) someone can encounter if they use short-circuiting like:

`variable && dosomething() || dosomethingelse()`

or

`variable && dosomething() //otherwise do nothing and continue`

instead of:

`variable ? dosomething() : dosomethingelse()`, `if (variable) { dosomething() } else { dosomethingelse }`

or

`variable ? dosomething() : null //or void, 0, 42`, `if (variable) {dosomething()}`

I've read this answer: [Omitting the second expression when using the if-else shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069278/omitting-the-second-expression-when-using-the-if-else-shorthand) and I wanted to know more.

Comment: i don't see any issue as long as variable is declared or initialized !!!

Comment: So the list of troubles is null!!! :)