# javascript if else shorthand and strings

Tags: javascript

```js
var x = 'x' 
x-'m'||console.log('True 1') 
// logs True, should be false

var x = '2' 
x-2||console.log('True 2') 
// logs True

var x = '3' 
x-2||console.log('True 3') 
// logs False
```

Why does this if else shorthand always return true when using a string? How can it be fixed?

I learnt this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069278/omitting-the-second-expression-when-using-the-if-else-shorthand)

Comment: `NaN` is falsy. it logs only the first with `NaN` and the second with zero.

Comment: Last condition doesn't log false for me

Comment: I think by "logs false" he means "doesn't go in the console.log".

Comment: @Aioros Correct

Comment: How are you reading the expression `x-'m'||console.log('True 1') ` : `x-( 'm'||console.log('True 1') )` - so "should not log anything because `'m'` is truthy" or `( x-'m' ) ||console.log('True 1')` - "should not log anything because `x-'m'` is truthy"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the expression before the `||` returns a `falsy` expression, then the `console.log()` is executed. This happens for the first expression `'x' - 'm'` which produces **`NaN`** (which is falsy):

```js
console.log('x' - 'm')
```

and for the second expression `'2' - 2` which returns **`0`** (which is falsy):

```js
console.log('2' - 2)
```

Your `console.log()` does not get executed for the third expression `'3' - 2` because that returns **`1`** (which is truthy):

```js
console.log('3' - 2)
```