# JS default operand

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I thought I understood how the default operand worked in JavaScript, but clearly not. I'm trying to first determine the user's geographic position, and load a map centered on those coordinates. If the device is unable to determine those coordinates, it would fallback to just loading the map with some default values.

You'll notice that in my error method, I'm calling `gMap.init()` with no arguments, which I thought should mean that the variables `lat` and `lon` should be set to 57.700992 and 11.893836 respectively. Instead, I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined`. Where am I going wrong?

Also, in `theApp.init()` I'm calling the map if `navigator.geolocation` exists. Does that mean browsers that don't support HTML5 geolocation will not even try loading the map?

```
var gMap = {
    init: function (position) {

            var lat = position.coords.latitude || 57.700992,
                lon = position.coords.longitude || 11.893836,
                geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder(),
                mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 12,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
                },
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcanvas'), mapOptions);

    },
    error: function () {
        console.log('failed to retrieve geoposition');
        gMap.init();
    }
}


var theApp = {
    init: function () {

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(gMap.init, gMap.error, {timeout:10000});
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you're talking about `||`, it's not the "default operand", it's the "logical OR operator". The error you're getting is nothing to do with that operator, it is because `position` is `undefined` so `position.coords` is an error. Try `lat = position && position.coords.latitude || 57.700992`

Comment: `position.coords` position is undefined, you can't access a property of an undefined variable.

Comment: Sorry, it _is indeed_ called the default operand. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378619/javascript-operator) and [here](http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html).

Comment: Defaulting operator is an alias for the OR operator in JavaScript due to its peculiar behaviour.

Comment: It's not an "operand" at all, it's an "operator". The operands are the expressions it operates on, in your case `position.coords.latitude` and `57.700992`. It's _normally_ called "logical OR" operator because in most languages and in JS with boolean operands that's what it does, though JavaScript has a kind of special implementation of logical OR that allows it to be used on non-booleans which is why you can use it to help set default values in certain cases.

Comment: although I'm not really into it, coffee script would make this task easier : `position?.coords?.latitude || 'default' `

Comment: Alright. Whatever. @nnnnnn if you submit an answer containing `lat = position && position.coords.latitude || 57.700992`, I'll mark it as correct. It looks pretty elegant to me, and I've learned from it.

Comment: Cerbrus's answer covers the same ground and more, no need for me to duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `||` you have there should work, **unless** `position.coords` or `position` is undefined. In that case, JavaScript will throw a error because you're trying to access a property on a undefined object.
You will have to manually check if the objects exist:

```
var lat, lon;
if(position && position.coords){
    lat = position.coords.latitude || 57.700992;
    lon = position.coords.longitude || 11.893836;
}
```

If `position` is undefined, the `if` will abort, without trying to check for `position.coords`.
(The `&&` doesn't evaluate the right parameter, if the left one is false)

And yes, if `navigator.geolocation` is undefined, the map will not be loaded:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(gMap.init, gMap.error, {timeout:10000});
```

This ^ will not be executed, so `gMap.init` will not be executed.

Comment: I wrote it like this instead: `lat = position && position.coords.latitude || 57.700992`, but great answer nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: I prefer using the `if` here, because you're only evaluating `position` / `position.coords` once. But both work, and yours is more compact. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You should try

```
 var lat = position.coords.latitude ? window['position'] != undefined : 57.700992,
 lon = position.coords.longitude ? window['position'] != undefined : 11.893836,
```

instead of `||`

Comment: `ReferenceError: position is not defined`

Comment: that was an impulsive answer, my bad