# Javascript difference between || and ?:

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

As I understand from [Javascript || operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378619/javascript-operator),
`||` will return whichever operand is true, and
`?:` will return the 1st operand if the condition before `?` evaluates to true, the 2nd otherwise.

But can `||` be considered as a ternary operator itself or not? Explain.

Comment: "Ternary operator" refers to having three operands. Does `||` have three operands? Nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `||` operator is binary because it has only two operands: `condition1 || condition2`.

`?:` is ternary because it has three operands: `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`.

Comment: didn't quite realize that at the time of posting, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The `||` operator can be seen as a special case of the `?:` operator . The following snippets are identical:

```
var c = a || b;
```

```
var c = a ? a : b;
```

Comment: of course with a bit of terrible hackery by using accessors that change their own state they could be made to produce different results, but that's certainly an edge case.