# What is the difference between declaring a function as a variable?

Tags: javascript

Does this produce the same results? What if function foo does not exist?

```
var foo = foo || function(){
  console.log("I'm Batman");
}
```

vs

```
var foo = function() {
  console.log("I'm Batman")
}
```

Comment: What if `foo` already exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a way of declaring `foo` *if and only if it has not already been declared* in some other scope. If it has, then the new, more local `foo` shall be identical to the broader one.

It works because of what `||` does and because `foo` is `undefined` if it's not, um, defined.

The whole thing is pretty rare, though, and not [one of the usual ways to declare a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/560648).

Comment: This is wrong. If `foo` was declared in a broader scope, the local one won't be the same. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30020514/1529630).

Comment: Then I must be misunderstanding your answer :) But  understand you say that if `foo` was not declared in a local scope, but is declared in a broader one (and has a truthy value), the local value will be identical to the broader one. That won't happen.

Comment: @Oriol: Oh I see: the new `foo` is in scope in its own initializer. If so then, yes, you're right: this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is known as **guard operator** ... one feature of javascript

```
x = a || b;

// if the first is true will return the first. Else will return the second;
```

Look more about in this question:

*[Javascript || operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378619/javascript-operator)*

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

The code does this (more or less):

- If `foo` was not declared in the current scope, it declares it and sets its value to `undefined`. If it's already declared, it remains declared with the same value.
- It checks if the value of `foo` is truthy.

  - If it's truthy, the value of `foo` is not changed
  - If it's falsy, `foo` is overwritten with the new value.

Therefore

- If `foo` was not declared in the current scope, it is declared, and the new value is assigned.

  ```js
  var foo = 123; // Another scope
  (function() {
      var foo = foo || 'abc';
      foo; // 'abc'
  })();
  ```
- If `foo` was declared in the current scope and its value was falsy, `foo` is overwritten with the new value.

  ```js
  var foo = ''; // Same scope, falsy value
  var foo = foo || 'abc';
  foo; // 'abc'
  ```
- If `foo` was declared in the current scope and its value was truthy, `foo` is not altered.

  ```js
  var foo = 123; // Same scope, truthy value
  var foo = foo || 'abc';
  foo; // 123
  ```