# JavaScript While Loop Conditional Abberation

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am curious as to why this while loop is not breaking as expected.  It is my understanding that when using the OR operator (||), if any of the conditions are found to be false, the loop breaks.

However, I noticed in a test document (I am learning JS for the first time) that my while loop is requiring ALL conditions to be found false before breaking.

This is a stub example:

```
var stringName="", numhours=0, numRate=0;

document.write("Exit at any time by entering -1");
while (stringName != "-1" || numHours != -1 || numRate != -1){
    stringName = prompt("Enter name","");
    numHours = prompt("Enter num hours","");
    numHours = parseFloat(numHours);
    numRate = prompt("Enter rate per hour","");
    numRate = parseFloat(numRate);
}
```

I would like it so that a user can enter -1 at any stage, and once the loop completes, it will re-check the conditions again, and after finding that the it is false that the name does not equal "-1", or false that the hours does not equal -1, or that it is false that the wage does not equal -1, it will break the loop.

Instead, it seems the loop is requiring that all of those conditions are met to exit, where name == "-1" AND hours == -1 AND wage == -1, only then will it break.

Any insight would be appreciated.  You guys rock!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript || operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378619/javascript-operator)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have your understanding of the `OR` operator backwards. You're treating it like `AND`.

Instead of:

> It is my understanding that when using the OR operator (||), if any of the conditions are found to be false, the loop breaks.

It's actually

> If any of the conditions are found to be true, the loop continues.

To fix the problem you can rewrite your loop to be:

```
while (stringName !== "-1" && numHours !== -1 && numRate !== -1)
```

Also it is preferable to use `!==` instead of `!=` because `!=` does something weird called type coercion that can give you results you don't expect.

Comment: This helps me understand my mistake.  All of your answers are on the money, by the way, but AR7 really helped me understand the reason a bit better.

Comment: @AR7 Can you provide an example where != does weird thing? Thanks

Comment: @VietNguyen sorry didn't see this earlier. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: @AR7 Perhaps starting coding from C++ prevent me from seeing the weird thing as it is perfectly normal for == op as per your link's answers whilst === is a little more strict on type conversion that could give me an unexpected result such as 0===false is false which is weird for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You have it backwards. The `||` operator evaluates to `true` if either operand has a "truthy" value (`true`, non-`null`, etc.). Your `while` loop will exit only when **all** the individual inequality tests are `false`. If you want it to exit when *any* of them is `false`, use the `&&` operator instead.

Comment: Thank you, too.  This is very helpful.  I don't recall C or Java working this way...

Comment: @TedHopp, thank you for clarifying.  I now find myself wondering how I've gotten this far. lol.  You fellas have been very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`while(condition)` will loop until condition == false.

Your question can be answered when we test this using the console:
`true||false||false||false||true` will evaulate to `true`

since OR statements evaluate to true if any one of their conditions are true.

[Logical OR Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_())